# BU2505FV current capability

Tags: dac, power-consumption

I plan to use the [BU2505FV](https://www.mouser.fr/datasheet/2/348/bu2506fv-e-1018387.pdf) Digital Analogic Converter in my design. After some simulations on LTSpice I've concluded that each of the analog output will consume 700µA maximum.

Is this component able to deliver 0.7mA on each of its pins ? 
I see that its maximum consumption current is 7.5mA, should I divide it by ten to know how much current the part can deliver on each output?

Here is the schematic of the circuit, the DAC output will go on the DAC label (low right corner of the schematic): 
[image]

Also I added the simulation results, with:

- in red the drain current of the NPN,
- in blue the circuit output (there is an amplification stage on the right)
- in green, the DAC variation

[image]

Thank you for your help

Comment: see the "Buffer amplifier output drive range" parameter.

Comment: so it means it can drive 2mA maximum ? And 200µA per output, in worst condition ?

Comment: Is this a modulator schematic ? Because it's a very strange and nonlinear, temperature dependent  one. U2 is an operational amplifier ? Then what is the purpose of R3 and C3 in parallel with the output? Also C1 is in parallel with the DAC output, it's unusual, it might raise the output current over the maximum allowed at a step voltage output.

Comment: from yesterday and today I removed the resistor at the U2 ouput. The C1 capacitor is a decoupling capacitor, removes the alternative part of the signal.

Answer (score 2):

> Is this component able to deliver 0.7mA on each of its pins ?

Yes it can deliver that current but that current comes with a price; output voltage reliability. See this graph from the data sheet: -

[image]

So with 0 mA taken the output is nominally 2.502 volts. If you take current from the output pin that voltage drops slightly. If current goes into the pin, the voltage rises slightly.

If you look elsewhere in the data sheet it tells you what the output impedance of each analogue output is and that is typically 5 ohms but can be as high as 15 ohms.

So, if you want accuracy, don't take current from the pins and use an external buffer if necessary.

You should also note that with a maximum of 100 uA in or out of the pin, the output voltage limits are 0.1 volts to 4.9 volts. This falls to 0.2 volts and 4.75 volts when the current is 1 mA.

Comment: What do you call an external buffer ? [link](https://electronique-radioamateur.fr/elec/schema/img/AOP-suiveur.JPG) Such circuit ?

Comment: Yes, an op-amp can do the job but only you know what it has to drive so I can't really recommend anything other than a device that is rail-to-rail and has a low offset voltage.

Comment: The output goes into a 180kOhm serial resistor connected to the base of a NPN transistor, which I want to control in linear region. [Here](http://grosfi.ch/zB2cZd27AHQuv) you can find my schematic.

Comment: I think you should add that diagram to your question. I didn't look at it because I don't do file downloads unless I know the person sending it. Not being rude; just careful.

Comment: It's done I've upload a picture of my circuit

Comment: The circuit you have shown will not take more than 80 uA so where do you think 700 uA will be needed?

Comment: The 700µA I've measure were on the NPN Drain. I work with pulsed signals in the label Vcell which may vary in the range [0,61mV ; 8V] and with big pulse I have the current described above. But indeed on the gate, the current is much lower than 700µA.

Comment: @RPerun The graph is consistent with buffer amplifier output impedance given in page 4 as 5 to 15 ohm, he can simulate this by adding a resistor with this value in series with DAC input. The error can be compensated by scaling on a later stage.